# Does "Active Wizard" work with Alfresco community 4.2?

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I'm working on Alfresco Community version 4.2.c. I want to deploy the "Active Wizard" tool provided by Technology Services Group [here is their website](http://www.tsgrp.com/index.jsp). My questions are

1. Can it be deployed on the community version or just the enterprise?
2. Does it work with alfresco community 4.2 where the last version of the "Active Wizard" is from 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the company. Active wizard is just support the Alfresco enterprise version. Active Wizard tool is free, just they charge for support.

Answer (score 1):

Most 4.0 addons needs to be modified to run in 4.2
You should really ask tsg guys themselves...